# I'm getting these in deployment error, how to solve them ? I'm just confused where to start?

Tags: deployment

I go them during deployment, I don't know where to start how do I fix these?

````
 - Error in GlobalValueSet component 'Country': CustomField not found.
 - Error in RecordType component 'Lead.Lead_Germany': Picklist value: Belgium in picklist: AddressCountry__c not found
 - Error in RecordType component 'Opportunity.Mexican_Box_Opportunity': Picklist value: New Line in picklist: BoxContractType__c not found
 - Error in RecordType component 'Opportunity.German_Box_Opportunity': Picklist value: New Line in picklist: BoxContractType__c not found
 - Error in RecordType component 'Opportunity.Belgian_Box_Opportunity': Picklist value: New Line in picklist: BoxContractType__c not found
 - Error in RecordType component 'Lead.Lead_Mexico': Picklist value: Belgium in picklist: AddressCountry__c not found
 - Error in RecordType component 'PersonAccount.PersonAccount_Mexico': Global value set 'Representative_Document_Type__c' in record type 'PersonAccount_Mexico' on the entity 'Account' cannot be resolved
 - Error in RecordType component 'PersonAccount.PersonAccount_Belgium': Global value set 'Representative_Document_Type__c' in record type 'PersonAccount_Belgium' on the entity 'Account' cannot be resolved
 - Error in RecordType component 'PersonAccount.PersonAccount_Germany': Global value set 'Representative_Document_Type__c' in record type 'PersonAccount_Germany' on the entity 'Account' cannot be resolved
 - Error in RecordType component 'Lead.Lead_Belgium': Picklist value: Belgium in picklist: AddressCountry__c not found
 - Error in Layout component 'Opportunity-Box Layout Mexico': In field: field - no CustomField named Opportunity.feedback_supervisor__c found
 - Error in Layout component 'PersonAccount-PersonAccount_Mexico': In field: field - no CustomField named PersonAccount.Representative_FirstName__c found
 - Error in Layout component 'Opportunity-Box Layout Belgium': In field: field - no CustomField named Opportunity.feedback_supervisor__c found
 - Error in Layout component 'PersonAccount-PersonAccount_Germany': In field: field - no CustomField named PersonAccount.Representative_FirstName__c found
 - Error in Layout component 'Opportunity-Box Layout Germany': In field: field - no CustomField named Opportunity.feedback_supervisor__c found
 - Error in Layout component 'PersonAccount-PersonAccount_Belgium': In field: field - no CustomField named PersonAccount.Representative_FirstName__c found
 - Error in ApexClass component 'SM030_TaskTriggerHandler': Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void createCallbackRequests(List<Task>, Map<Id,Task>, Map<Id,SM017_CallbackTask.WhoWhatInfoResult>) from the type SM017_CallbackTask
```
````

Comment: "The journey of 1000 miles begins with a single step." Or something like that. | Please elaborate on the word "deployment" - how are you attempting to deploy?

Comment: Hi Moonpie, I'm trying to deploy using BlueCanvas tool, the new record type into a high org for deployment. The record types are new but the field . Sorry I'm actually can't comprehend suddenly. Where should I start how I start correcting. Box Contract Type is a field, I added both the field and recordtype but Im still facing error

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're missing the following Custom Fields:

> Lead.AddressCountry__c
>
> Opportunity.BoxContractType__c
>
> Opportunity.feedback_supervisor__c
>
> Contact.Representative_FirstName__c

As well as the GlobalValueSet:

> Representative_Document_Type__c

And the ApexClass:

> SM017_CallbackTask

Depending on your deployment tool, you'll need to either retrieve those files, select those files, or select those files as part of the deployment.

You may want to [build a Package](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.creating_packages.htm&type=5) to make sure that you grab all the correct dependencies. Most modern tools allow you to down the entire contents of a package at once, which can make it much easier to make sure you have the files you need to deploy.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox 
I removed some and added some fields. The first error is because some values are not allowed in Global Value set and Country is one among them, I worked around by add the country values directly in the higher org.